# $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, |f'(x)| \leqslant C |f(x)|$ implies $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives, roots

**Question**

> Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^1$ a function such that $f(0)=0$ and $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, |f'(x)| \leqslant C |f(x)|$.
> Prove that $f=0$

**My attempt**

If there exists $a$ such that $f(a)\neq 0$, then in a neighborhood of $a$ we can write $-c \le \frac{f'}{f} \le c$ and we can integrate between $a$ and $x$ in this neighborhood :
$-c(x-a) \le \ln(f(x)) - \ln(f(a)) \le c(x-a)$ so $\exp(-c(x-a)) \le \frac{f(x)}{f(a)} \le \exp(c(x-a)) (*)$.

Without loosing generality we can suppose $a>0$. Let $b = \max \{ a > x \ge 0, f(x)=0\}$ (exists since $f(0)=0$). Then when $x\rightarrow b$ we get in $(*)$ : $\exp(-c(b-a)) \le 0$. This is impossible. So we get the result.

---

First I'm not sure of my proof.

Then I think there might be other proofs, and surely easier ones.

Could someone help ?

Comment: Look up the Bellman Grönwall inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Pick $T>0$ such that $TC <1$ and consider $f$ on $[0,T]$. We have
$|f(t)| \le \int_0^t C |f(x)| dx$ and so with $\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{t \in [0,T]} |f(t)|$ we have $\|f\|_\infty \le CT \|f\|_\infty$ from which we have $f(t) = 0$ for $t \in [0,T]$.

Comment: It is a hint. The above establishes that $f(t) = 0$ for $t \in [0,T]$. So start from $T$ and repeat. The same analysis can be applied in a reverse direction, mutatis mutandis.